# The menu bar in Ubuntu 14.04 disappeared

Tags: 14.04, panel

I downloaded add-on Character Palette which ended up in the same location as the Menu Bar, which then went into the top panel on the desktop. I removed Character Palette, but Menu Bar remains in the Panel, not on Window. In other words, the Menu bar is now inside the Panel on the desktop and shows when I am online like now. File Edit View History Bookmarks Tools Help are in the Panel. I tried refreshing Firefox, customize menu (there is no Menu Bar in drop down menu), restore default. What command can I use in Terminal to get Menu bar back on the window?

Answer (score 1):

Open System Settings, click on "Appearance", click on the "Behavior" tab, then, under "Show the menus for a window", select "In the window's title bar".
[image: behavior tab]

Comment: Thre is no Behavior tab in Appearance. It is not a window title bar I need, it is the menu bar which goes above the address or search bar

Comment: @dustbindva I added a screenshot circling the behavior tab. And no, this does not move the title bar around; it moves menu bars to just under their window's title bar.

Comment: I dont have that same dialog box in Appearance in my version.  It shows Style, Icons,  Fonts, Settings,  it is not the same as your screenshot. But I resolved my issue. I removed the indicator plug-in from the  panel and the menu bar returned to the window.